# selecting two rows that match a Foreign id?

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get all the movies_name that belong in two genres(categroies),

i.e. SCHEMA

```
movie_id  genre
4         Action
4         Comedy
```

SQL:

```
SELECT movies.movie_name
FROM movies
INNER JOIN tags
ON movies.movie_id = tags.movie_id
WHERE tags.genre = 'Comedy'
AND tags.genre = 'Action'
```

this should bring me back the movie_name of movie_id 4.

this brings me back zero results, when i know thier should be three results using my test data, am i doing the query wrong.

Comment: you have to use a OR or a In Statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT movies.movie_name
FROM movies
INNER JOIN tags
ON movies.movie_id = tags.movie_id
WHERE tags.genre IN ('Comedy','Action')
GROUP BY movies.movie_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

if unique constraint was not specified on genre for each movie then you need to add `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT movies.movie_name
FROM movies
INNER JOIN tags
ON movies.movie_id = tags.movie_id
WHERE tags.genre IN ('Comedy','Action')
GROUP BY movies.movie_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.genre) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*example data is different but still have same thought*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960fd/9)

Comment: thanks that works, will mark ur answer right when they let me :) +1

Comment: I'd have gone with a double join, but this is cleaner. +1.

Comment: can you explain to me the last line, `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`

Comment: @unknown because `movies.movie_name` is expected to return two rows because it will match on both condition by the `IN` clause. try executing this `SELECT movies.movie_name
FROM movies
INNER JOIN tags
ON movies.movie_id = tags.movie_id
WHERE tags.genre IN ('Comedy','Action')`

Answer (score 0):

`Tags.genre` cannot be BOTH 'Comedy' and 'Action' **at the same time**. You need an `IN` clause like such:

`SELECT fields FROM tables WHERE tags.genre IN ('Comedy', 'Action')

Comment: this will still the movie return if it has atleast one genre that is in the `IN` clause.